# Assign value to php class const

Tags: php

I am not at all good in oop concept but i tried

```
final class my_class
{
    const VALUE = "test";
    const VALUE1 = "test";
}
```

this is working

```
$some = 'test';    
final class my_class
{
    const VALUE = $some;
    const VALUE1 = "test";
}
```

this is not working why?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PHP5 currently doesn't support this.

If you want this feature, you have to wait for PHP5.6 which added constant scalar expressions: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs

That means, you can use constant scalar expressions to define constants - something like `const VALUE = $var;` still wont work for some good reasons.

If you really want to define some runtime constants, you have to use `define()` or manipulate classes with runkit(`runkit_constant_add`)